# spring with plain jdbc and transaction management - transaction not maintane

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions, spring-jdbc

I am working on Spring with jersey rest Webservice. i have used spring transaction support for transaction management. But transaction it is not working. Here are my configuration:

datasource.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        p:jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" p:user="pass" p:password="root"
        p:acquireIncrement="5" p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60" p:maxPoolSize="100"
        p:maxStatements="50" p:minPoolSize="10" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
 
    <!-- Enable Annotation based Declarative Transaction Management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

dao classes

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    @Transactional
    public class CustomerDao {
        public void insertCustomer() {
                //insertion with plain jdbc like catch exception and rethrow it
        }
    }
```

caller

```
            Product product= new Product();
            customerDao.insertCustomer(product.getCustumer());
            prderDao.insertOrder(product.getOrder());
     
            ctx.close();
```

isssue > After throwing exception in  product.getOrder, data is still persist in customer table.

Comment: And why should the transaction be maintained? The `@Transactional` gives the transactional boundry, ie. it starts on entering the method and ends after the method cal. So after the `insertCustomer` the transaction ends. Your caller (in general your service layer) should be transactional not the dao layer.

Comment: @M.Deinum i want transaction should be start just before 'customerDao.insertCustomer(product.getCustumer());' and end after 'prderDao.insertOrder(product.getOrder());' so if error is thrown at insertOrder insert customer should be rollback

Comment: and as per my reading ,using @Transactional at both dao and service layer , it uses default propagation behavior that is PROPAGATION_REQURIED. so if issue occurs in second transaction first transaction gets rollback

Comment: What I see in what you provided is that only your daos are annotated nothing else. Something that makes me a little scared is `ctx.close()` which makes me wonder if you are constructing a new `ApplicationContext` each time you need the dao, instead of using dependency injection. Also `@Transactional` on a Jersey managed bean isn't going to work it will only work on Spring managed beans.

Comment: sorry for this but , This is just sample code of my app as i cannot paste my code on internet.My app is web application. and i annotade both serviceObject and Dao object with @Transactional. and in service calling multiple dao method. where i am expecting to manage transaction

Comment: If you cannot post your code on internet, consider creating a sample application mirroring your web app (but changing package names etc.) and provide that for investigation.